# How do I turn off styles for the div, or set to use just one css file?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, web, github

I have a site http://jsreport.net/learn/get-started on which I put into the body of the page documentation files from Github (which have the extension .md). Directly into the html I inserted inline css styles for styling documentation like on Github. The problem is that these style cross with my other styles and documentation are not displayed correctly (likes on the  Github site). Could anyone advise me any solution how I can for my div prohibit other styles or any other solution? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You should look into CSS specifity, to get your problem fixed.

Here is a good article about it:

[CSS Specifity](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/)

Inline styles are privileged compared to your stylesheet declarations. You could use the `!important` declaration in your stylesheet to overrule this. But this bad practice, the best approach for you would be to resign from inline styles and just use your stylesheet.

Comment: So, what I have to do it - clean styles or can I use some jQuery sript for blocking styles and allow only inline styles for div.. ?

Comment: No, you should definitely write clean styles. By overwriting it with javascript you will most probably run into more problems the long way..

Answer (score 0):

add !important, like:

```
display: none !important;
```

Comment: This solution would be alright if there were just a few overriding issues, but it gets pretty messy if you start doing that for a lot of elements. Best option in the long run would be moving styles to an external stylesheet.